# Extract an element that does not have an xml:lang attribute

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following xml file:

```xml
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <sample>Foo</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="a">abc</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="b">efj</sample>
    </component>
</components>
```

```py
from lxml import etree

def parse(path: str):

    return etree.parse(path)

def components(path: str) -> list:

    components = parse(path).xpath("/components/component")
    return list(components)

def sample(path: str) -> str:
    sample = components(path)[0].find("sample").text

    return str(sample)

path = "test.xml"
print(sample(path))
```

I want to go through all the `sample` tags and get the value of the one that has no `xml:lang` attribute, ie. the first one. How would I do that? I know I'll need to use a for loop, but not sure how to check if `xml:lang` is present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `lang` is not in attributes of the tag:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_string = """
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <sample>Foo</sample>
        <sample lang="a">abc</sample>
        <sample lang="b">efj</sample>
    </component>
</components>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

for sample in root.findall("component/sample"):
    if "lang" not in sample.attrib:
        print(sample.text)
```

Prints:

```
Foo
```

---

EDIT: If you have namespace `xml:` you can try:

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_string = """
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <sample>Foo</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="a">abc</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="b">efj</sample>
    </component>
</components>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

for sample in root.findall("component/sample"):
    # use http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace here for xml: namespace
    # or other Namespace URI found in your document (for different namespaces)
    lang = sample.attrib.get(r"{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang")
    if not lang:
        print(sample.text)
```

Comment: Looks like I simplified my example a bit. In my case the attribute is `xml:lang` which gets expanded to the namespace. How would I check then?

Comment: "or other Namespace URI found in your document" - What do you mean by that? The `xml` prefix is reserved and cannot be bound to any other namespace URI than `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.

Comment: @mzjn My bad, I should've been more specific. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The only namespace that applies to the question is `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. There are no other namespaces, so why do you even mention "other Namespace URI"?

Comment: @mzjn The answer will be read afterwards by many other people. If there is another namespace than `xml:`, for example `<components version="1.0.0" xmlns:ex="http://example.com">` then you can search for the attribute `lang = sample.attrib.get(r"{http://example.com}lang")` (if you have e.g. `<sample ex:lang="example">Foo</sample>`) Is it clear?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, you can change `sample.attrib.get() `to shorter `sample.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (now with namespaces for attrib:** You can check with `tagname.get('attrib_argument')`:

```
from lxml import etree as et

xml_str = """<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <sample>Foo</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="a">abc</sample>
        <sample xml:lang="b">efj</sample>
    </component>
</components>
"""

root = et.fromstring(xml_str)
   
for elem in root.findall('.//sample'):
    if elem.get('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang') is not None:
        pass
    else:
        print(f"sample <tag> on list position {root.findall('.//sample').index(elem)} has no 'lang' attrib, Text: {elem.text}")
```

Output:

```
sample <tag> on list position 0 has no 'lang' attrib, Text: Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using core python xml lib (no external lib like in the other answers)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <sample>Foo</sample>
        <sample lang="a">abc</sample>
        <sample lang="b">efj</sample>
    </component>
</components>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
samples_with_no_lang = [s.text for s in root.findall('.//sample') if s.attrib.get('lang') is None]
print(samples_with_no_lang)
```

output

```
['Foo']
```